# How to implement scroll view in xib cocoa objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, scrollview

In order to implement scroll view I do:

1. Create Cocoa Application
2. Go to XIB
3. Drag scroll view to the view window and set its constraints to 0

Everything seems fine until now

4. Under Bordered Scroll View (in the Document Outline) I press on Clip View and then View and resize that to any large number (under size inspector)
5. I add a button (for the sake of it) to the view (under clip view) (in the Document Outline) and sets its constraints

After this I immediately get the "Ambigious Layout. Position is ambigious for "View".

What am I doing wrong? Is this the proper way to add scrollview? It also seems rather difficult to add items to the scrollable area as I dont see the entire scrollable area in the xib.

Please help a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is a correct way to add a scroll view. (You can also create a view or set of sibling views, select them, and choose Editor > Embed In > Scroll View.)

If a view has no constraints, then Xcode will add sufficient constraints at build time. These constraints are not necessarily the ones that cause the view to behave like you want as things change size, but they're good enough to maintain the current layout of the canvas when things have their current sizes.

However, once you add constraints, Xcode will start insisting that the constraints are mutually-compatible (no conflicts) and sufficient to be unambiguous.

So, that explains why you get that warning. You have added some constraints, but not enough to make the layout unambiguous. You need to add enough. Xcode should explain in more detail what's needed, although there will necessarily be multiple possibilities for how to resolve the ambiguity.

In your case, I'm guessing that the size of the view in the scroll view is ambiguous. For example, you may have added constraints to position the button relative to the top and leading edge, and the button likely has intrinsic size, but you haven't constrained the view's bottom or trailing edges to the button. So, the size of the view could be anything.

Of course, rather than constraining the view's bottom and trailing edge to the button, you could just add explicit height and width constraints to it. Or whatever.

You may also need to constrain the view to the clip view.

You can also use Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Add Missing Constraints and see what Xcode adds. You can then change things from there if what Xcode added is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was very helpful.
Do you also happen to know how to populate buttons in the scrollable area? My view is much larger than the app and I cannot just drag the button wherever I want

Comment: Well, ultimately, the button's position will be determined by the constraints. So, you can add constraints and modify their values to get the button where you want it. You would use Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Update Frames to make the position on the canvas match what the constraints determine. OR, you can position the buttons by editing the X, Y, Width, and Height in the Size inspector and then use Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Update Constraints to make the constraints match the new position.

Comment: Or, you could add the buttons and their constraints to the view programmatically. This may be easiest if the buttons are positioned in some regular pattern. Or, you could design the view in a separate NIB and add it to the scroll view programmatically. This way, the scroll view won't hamper your access to the view. If you have constraints between the document view and the clip view, you'd also have to set those up programmatically after adding the document view. Whenever you add views programmatically and are using auto layout, don't forget to clear `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

Answer (score 0):

For my **Mac OS X app**, I selected the controls on xib to embed in scroll view ( **Editor > Embed In > Scroll View** ) and applying the following constraints to **Custom View** (inside Scroll View -> Clip View) did work.

[image]

Where **hight** is to accommodate controls.